# Simple product not display in categories

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product

I created configurable products and **relative simple products** ( visibility set in Catalog/Search ) but i can not see simple products in categories pages.

Comment: Hi Yavonz15, welcome to Magento SE! You are giving very little information in your question. Please edit your question and add what you have tried so far and what you are trying to achieve. What is working and what isn't. If you have written code, please provide samples of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see your products in catalog, search, you need to make sure lot of other things. It is best explained [**here**](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/). In short, it will be

- active
- visible in catalog search
- should have an inventory
- should be in stock etc.

Please go through the above given link and make sure everything is configured correctly in your system.

Comment: I not have assigned Category.